# Kendo Grid - Dont allow certain records for editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the below command button column in my Kendo grid..

How to disable the "Edit" button in the rows with empty "ItemValue".

```
$("#list485").kendoGrid({
     dataSource: dataSource,
     columns: [
                        { command: [{ name: "edit" }], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px"},
                        {   field: "ItemValue", title: "Item Description" }
    ],
    editable: "popup" 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may hide edit button by on dataBound function as below

```
dataBound: function (e) {
                     var grid = $("#list485").data("kendoGrid");
                     var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();
                     for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
                         var currentUid = gridData[i].uid;
                         if (gridData[i].ItemValue == "") {
                             var currenRow = grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentUid + "']");
                             var editButton = $(currenRow).find(".k-grid-edit");
                             editButton.hide();
                         }
                     }
                 }
```

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can fulfill your need but it works fine for inline editing.

```
 $("#list485").kendoGrid({
 dataSource: dataSource,
 columns: [
                    { command: [{ name: "edit" }], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px"},
                    {   field: "ItemValue", title: "Item Description" }
],
editable: "popup",
edit: function(e) {
          if(e.model.ItemValue == 100)//your condition
             {
              $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
             }
       }
});
```

Anyway this is what I could able to find till now.
There must be some better solution for this.